# Why do some students wear headbands during practice?

Tags: etiquette, uniform, tradition

I saw that at some schools of some martial arts many of the students wear headbands. They seem to only be in certain martial arts (like Karate), and I would almost never see it in others (like BJJ or Judo). Do these headbands have a historical or contextual meaning? If so, what do the different colors/patterns mean? Also, why are they worn in the first place? My first assumption was that they are there to soak up sweat, but then why aren't they worn in most martial arts?

Comment: Some information on the cultural significance in Japan - and for karate - at https://japandaily.jp/hachimaki-japanese-headband-gives-energy-4223/ 
My shinkyokushin sensei in Tokyo would very occasionally put one on if undertaking some very intense training.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Japanese martial arts and [Hachimaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachimaki), it's basically a matter of tradition that might be based off of samurai helmets and padding against cuts. These days, it's more ceremonial, and sometimes a method of advertising (hachimaki with slogans are passed out at trade shows), but they do still work to keep sweat out of your eyes.

> The origin of hachimaki is uncertain. The most common theory states that they originated as headbands worn by samurai to line their heads with cloth. This was to stop cuts from the helmet and make wearing the helmet more comfortable.

In Muay Thai, the [mongkoi](https://grantmma.ca/why-do-muay-thai-fighters-wear-headbands/) is entirely ceremonial, and is basically a sign of rank, much like belts are in many styles.

I have not found any reliable material on why some [Pencak Silat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencak_silat#Bali) fighters have it as part of the their uniform other than tradition.

Comment: I personally wear a headband during Capoeira because I sweat profusely with even a mild workout, and it does help keep my eyes clear of sweat, but it is not standard. Now if you asked why scarfs are traditional in some schools of Capoeira, that I can answer, although again, it's a mix of tradition and legend. :-P

Comment: Do you have any idea if different colors mean anything?

Comment: For *hakimashi*? Capoeira scarfs?

Comment: I was thinking more in the Japanese arts where it's super common to see them.

Comment: As far as I know, the colors have no formal meaning, although everything I've found so far indicates that red and white are the two colors acceptable in most styles that use *hachimaki*. I haven't found any reasoning why other than "tradition", but it probably has something to do with undyed cloth being cheaper and red being close to the color of blood ("Bring me my red shit/brown pants" and all that).